# Error module 'tablib.formats._xls' has no attribute 'title'

Tags: django

I have an issue in django, after click in import button in django admin site.
This is my code
code in admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    pass
```

in models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from import_export.admin import ImportMixin

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField()
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
```

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c81hc.png)

Comment: After going through documentation ( https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#admin-integration ), i think you should use something like `class PersonAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin): resource_class = PersonResource`.

Comment: I changed, but the error still appear. class PersonAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = PersonResource

Comment: did you create a `PersonResource` class as well?

Comment: I created in resources.py `from import_export import resources
from import_export.fields import Field
from .models import Person


class PersonResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('name', 'email', 'birth_date','location')`

Comment: Beside, Export doesnot appear any type of format, it is empty even it doesnot show error like Import

Answer (score 10):

I just faced the same issue, and solved it after wasting 4 hours...

#### Solution

Check the version of tablib and django-import-export that you're using.
Django-import-export 1.x only supports tablib version is up to 0.14.0.

You can install a specific version of tablib in pip using

```
pip install tablib==0.14.0
```

Alternatively, upgrade your django-import-export to a more recent version (2.x), where this incompatibility is fixed.

#### Explanation

Very recently, tablib upgraded to 1.0.0, during which the `format` class has changed.
Now, each file type (e.g. xlsx) is a class within the module.
django-import-export still expects the file types to be written in the old way, causing the error you see: no attribute 'title'.

Comment: The funny thing is if you use django-import-export==2.0.1, the "fix" is that it specifically lists  tablib==0.14.0 as one of its requirements so it also does not support tablib 1.0.0 but is smart enough not to install the latest version.

BTW, thanks for saving me 4 hours!